# What is the maximum stoarge limit for parse local data store in android

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform

I am using local data store for my app with parse.com android.
To improve the user experience and reduce the number of network calls, I want to store as much data related to user on the device itself in the localDataStore.

What is the maximum storage limit for parse local data store?
Also I want data to be retained in the local data store, even if the user logs out. Does logging out the user clears localDataStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse localDataStore simply create a sqlite db called "ParseOfflineStore" on devices.
The limitation should be the same with normal sqlite db(http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Logging out the user will not clear the data unless you unpin(remove) it.

Comment: Thank you. A related question again. Will the ACLs work in localDataStore or won't they have any effect?

Comment: ACL works the same whether you pin the object or not.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also please check this question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980212/request-parameters-in-a-post-request-in-parse-com)