# Parse.com webhook with Python on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, parse-platform, webhooks

My problem is I have created a web scraper in python and would like to access this web scraper using Parse's back-end. With Parse, you have the ability to create an app via Heroku, which works well considering you need a valid SSL to access webhooks from Parse, and you can certainly host python apps on Heroku. However, the documentation for creating an app from Parse with Heroku only explores nodejs and says if you're using another language to just create a webhooks.json file with valid information, but doesn't go over how to do this in any language examples and is kind of ambiguous. In addition, I'm pretty sure you should have to download some kind of library for Parse in python but I don't have that either. Basically, I would just like a tutorial on how to setup a Parse webhook written in Python via Heroku. Thanks.

Comment: How about host your python wherever you want, then call from parse with Cloud.httpRequest()?

Comment: The only thing is, I didn't really wanna pay for hosting services.

Comment: I know how that is.  But somebody must host python on a free tier, right?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know where to look would you? I don't have a lot of experience in hosting services or running websites.

Comment: Also, is it possible to pass in parameters to a page via Cloud.httpRequest()?

Comment: About PHP as a service, this looked promising (http://www.fortrabbit.com).  I don't know anything about it... just googled. Regarding invoking with parameters, you can give http request json that specifies a few things like the verb, headers, body, etc.  Demonstrate somewhat here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980212/request-parameters-in-a-post-request-in-parse-com

Comment: Oops, just read further at fortrabbit, and its not really very free (free for a short trial period).  Keep googling.

Comment: Interesting, I'll keep looking. Right now I'm looking into using node.js instead of python on Heroku. Node.js just isn't as good looking as python though and I don't think I'm a fan of it's asynchronous architecture.

Comment: Ok, I've setup a Python app in Heroku and can call the URL where the Python script is from Parse Cloud Code, but only with GET request. I get a 403 forbidden error when trying to use POST. Know anything that may help?

Comment: Does it work using CURL?

Comment: No, when I use curl for post request I get the html of the page and it says "Reason given for failure: Referer checking failed - no Referer

Comment: Probably related to this...https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-permissivecsrf/1.0.0

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. I'll try out the solution and let you know how it works. Thanks for all your help, by the way.

Comment: Unfortunately I installed permissivecsrf and sslify and I'm still getting "Referer checking failed - no Referer."

Comment: My problem is just with the Referer Headers, there seems to be some type of token to send in POST request to Heroku app but I don't know what that may be.

Comment: The parse.com tag (and me) will be helpful once you have the system ready to call out of parse (if you can CURL it, you're ready).  Until then, maybe write a new question about getting PHP as a service running, maybe here, maybe on http://serverfault.com

Comment: How exactly could I call the heroku site with CURL using POST? I need to add data to the request also, I've never really used CURL before but I have it installed on windows

Comment: CURL sends data with -d.  And I don't know how to invoke your PHP service from http bypassing it CSRF protection.  That's what I'm suggesting you find out in a new question (maybe on a different site).  Your most recent SO question has the same problem: your use of the httpRequest is fine, but you won't know exactly how to configure it until you figure out the CSRF problem.  CURL is just a quicker way to do that.

Comment: Ok, I just used a curl POST request to the app and I got the same 403 error. I don't know what  PHP service you're talking about though? I'm not using PHP in my app but I'm using Cloud Code from Parse which is JavaScript and Python on Heroku.

Comment: I just posted a question to serverfault

Comment: Ok, so I went back and wrote my httpRequest with GET and the scraper is called and everything, but when the string i'm trying to return is longer it doesn't seem to get back to Parse but when the string is shorter it does work. I don't know what's going on.