# What is the maximum database size (50 MB or 100 MB or 150MB ) that can be saved in local datastore in ios by using Parse API

Tags: ios, cordova, parse-platform

I need to store maximum data in local Datastore by using Parse API in iOS HYDRIDE APPLICATION. Can any one tell me how much (Maximum) of data is store in local datastore according to Parse API.

Thank you,
Madhav

Answer (score 0):

Think about Parse as a business. How does Parse make money? Off of queries and API request limits. If you go over a threshold of API request per second they charge you fees right? Thats how they make money, so more the better to them. So essentially you surpass their 30 per second then you may be subject to fees. Just remember your app can be as large as 2GB, but don't neglect your core audience and force them to download a 2GB app when you can update information as necessary. However, with that being said, any device, computer, regardless of its capacity, has limitations when memory and disk space is taken into consideration. Parse is an online resource, you should use it for that. PFQueryTableViewController is a powerful tool for Parse related executions, you should take advantage of that.

You can also set limits to queries with Parse, which is a good thing for those that like free stuff.

Also, here is a reference to your same question worth reviewing:

[What is the maximum stoarge limit for parse local data store in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825869/what-is-the-maximum-stoarge-limit-for-parse-local-data-store-in-android)